# Regex, match number with hyphen and without

Tags: regex

I have got this string `[lat:50.000]` and I need to get the number out of it, however sometimes it might have a hyphen at the front of it as it could be a minus number.

I have got this regex at the moment `[\-]\d+(\.\d{1,10})?` however it will only match the number if it has got the hyphen at the front, I need a regex that will match it with and without the hyphen. So I would be left with `50.000` or in some cases `-2.000`.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `\-?\d+\.\d{1,10}`

Comment: The hyphen doesn't even need to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You need a quantifier to state that the hyphen is optional:

```
[\-]?\d+(\.\d{1,10})?
```

You can also improve the expression a bit and put the hyphen out of the character class (since it's just one character):

```
-?\d+(\.\d{1,10})?
```

Comment: No need for a character class though. It could just be `-?`

Comment: Yes; I was trying not to disturb the original regular expression, so I added another version.

Answer (score 1):

A [question mark quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?` following a character or group will indicate that it is optional :

```
-?\d+(\.\d{1,10})?
```

This is the equivalent of using the `{0,1}` quantifier.

Comment: You can also remove the escape from the hyphen.

Comment: Thanks, it's a result of removing OP's original character group, but neglecting to knock off the escape.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another one:

```
(-?\d[\d.,]+)
# - or not (optional)
# followed by at least a digit
# followed by digits, dots and commas
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xK2wE8/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple expression

```
\-?\d*\.?\d*
```